# getting Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking(). error

Tags: python

I am new to pexpect module. i am getting this error during connection with remote server.
i am using below code:

```
main_server = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
        i = main_server.expect ([pexpect.TIMEOUT,
                   pexpect.EOF,
                   'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?',
                   'Host key verification failed.',
                   'Connection refused',
                   'Connection timed out',
                   'Connection closed by remote host',
                   'password:'])

        if i == 0:
              main_server.sendline("user time out")
              connect_remote_servers_tunnel(local_db_cursor,server_ip,\
              user_name,password,tunnel_user_name,\
              tunnel_password,system_ip,circle_code,circle_name,port_no,user,passwd)
        if i == 2:
              main_server.sendline ("yes")
              connect_remote_servers_tunnel(local_db_cursor,server_ip,\
              user_name,password,tunnel_user_name,\
              tunnel_password,system_ip,circle_code,circle_name,port_no,user,passwd)
        if i == 7:
              main_server.sendline (password)

        main_server.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        tables=main_server.before
        main_server.sendline('logout')
        main_server.read()
```

i serched for this error but not getting any solution.i provide the time out manually to change the default timeout of module which is 30 sec.but not getting any solution.Please provide the solution.

Comment: What error message did you get precisely? Please include that in your question. Also what is remote server you tried to connect to?

Comment: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x1546490>

i am connecting a linux machine by creating tunnel.tunnel are fine.but i am getting tis error during reading data from database.

Comment: have you tried `read_blocking()`?

Comment: At which position i can use it?